Did I just fry my piano keyboard aux outputs by sending them into an old effects pedal?
For a long time I have run guitar effects pedals with my keyboard rig with no problem. This particular setup is a Nord Stage 4 going out of the stereo aux sends into a Radial Stereo Reamp which increases the impedance to optimize the signal for sending through guitar effects pedals. I sent the audio into this reamp, mono out one side of its effects loop, and into my MoogerFooger RM-102 Ring Modulator, which  has a power demand of 9V Center Positive, which was being powered by its proprietary correct Moog DC adapter. This was sent back to the Radial Reamp effects loop return, and out from there into my Nord Monitors.
As soon as I tried playing out of it, I heard a single note, and then nothing. I turned everything off and began testing things individually. The Nord monitors work fine still with other aux inputs. The Moog pedal works fine with my guitar rig still. The Nord still outputs accurate MIDI to my computer as  well as retaining all other functionality. But it will not output volume out of the aux sends. The first couple times I was bug testing it would output a single note as I played right when it turned on and then go silent, but now it will not even do this.
Worth noting, there are 4 aux sends on the Nord Stage 4. I was coming out of only 1 and 2 when this happened, but now 3 and 4 dont make any noise whatsoever either. I have no idea what happened other than to catastrophize about something with this old Moog pedal having tripped and somehow fried part of the Nords circuitry.
I have no idea what went wrong, please help.

I can’t see how what you did would have damaged the Nord. Also the radial is completely unnecessary in this setup. Most guitar pedals can just take keyboard signals no problem, the Moogfoogers definitely can take keyboards with no problem. They are made by Moog after all!

Have you tried the Nord headphone outputs? Have you checked the settings in the Nord’s output menu? BTW, outputs 1-4 on the Nord Stage 4 are main outputs, not aux outputs. It has only five audio outs: the four main outputs plus the headphone out.

@ToddWilcox Thank you for the reply! I had not thought to check my headphone out. That is not working either. I had been routing outputs 1-4 correctly from the output menu, but still no sound. And about the reamp, yes yes I agree. The Moog certainly didnt need it, but I just leave the Nord routed through the reamp and back into the speakers all the time since I use pedals so much and so I always just throw whatever pedal Im using in the effects loop. I figured it cant hurt even if some pedals dont particularly need it and it saves me a lot of hastle rerouting. I have no idea what to do.

It got resolved! Just had to factory reset the Nord by downloading the Nord Sound Manager, the up-to-date factory reset file, and a Nord OS update! So relieved. Have no idea what tripped that happening with the Moog pedal, but just glad it doesnt require an expensive repair.

I doubt the pedal was part of the cause. More likely some kind of accidental button combination on the Nord dropped all the volume levels or something like that.

Mmm.  Other less likely possibilities which could cause a ‘soft’ problem include a spike in the power, or a cosmic ray.  And of course there's always the possibility of buggy software.  (All the obvious bugs would almost certainly have been fixed, but rare situations or timing issues might still be able to cause problems.)  I'm glad it was easily fixable!
